# MEmu emulator not loading websites contents

Tags: browser, android-emulator

I am having issues with MEmu emulator, I have recently just started using MEmu play emulator and Android 7.1 and each time I download the updated Google chrome, Firefox, & Opera browsers from play store they don't load website contents, the website will load and after a while a blank screen or white screen will follow.

JavaScript and all other features have been enabled by default and I didn't tamper with the default settings, What do I do to make the websites I visit on the browsers I mentioned above load and display normally.

I tried different browsers and other emulators works fine, but I don't know why I'm seeing a white or blank page on the websites that I visit

Comment: try this new browser:  https://www.memuplay.com/how-to-use-com.android.chrome-on-pc.html   AND    https://www.reddit.com/r/memuplayer/comments/tjnsfm/browsers_in_memu_doesnt_show_website_contents/